# Clear android application user data

Tags: android, adb, user-data

Using **adb shell** we can clear application data.

```
adb shell pm clear com.android.browser
```

But when executing that command from the application

```
String deleteCmd = "pm clear com.android.browser";      
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            runtime.exec(deleteCmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
```

**Issue:**

It doesn't clear the user data nor give any exception though I have given the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"/>
```

**Question:**

How to clear another app application data using **adb shell**?

Comment: Did you find any solution to clear data for outside application?

Comment: Don't think a 3rd party application should have permission to clear user data of another app. It would be a mess if that happened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afaik the Browser application data is NOT clearable for other apps, since it is store in `private_mode`. So executing this command could probalby only work on rooted devices. Otherwise you should try another approach.

Comment: The command line tools are not intdended for usage by applications.  Likely they will only work for the semi-privileged adb shell user, which is treated as somewhat comparable in authority to a user pushing buttons in GUI if the system settings app.

Answer (score 297):

This command worked for me:

```
adb shell pm clear packageName
```

Comment: is it possible to use adb for clearing the cache too?

Comment: @EduardoCuomo Of course. I meant : Is it possible to use adb for clearing only the cache, too ?

Comment: @Shayan You can checkout the following link to only delete the application cache : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589471/android-how-to-clear-app-cache-and-keep-user-data-via-adb    
I am not sure about this command will work or not.

Comment: Is there something similar, that is only for cache?

Answer (score 6):

The command `pm clear com.android.browser` requires root permission.
So, run `su` first.

**Here is the sample code:**

```
private static final String CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8";
String cmd = "pm clear com.android.browser";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().redirectErrorStream(true).command("su");
Process p = pb.start();

// We must handle the result stream in another Thread first
StreamReader stdoutReader = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream(), CHARSET_NAME);
stdoutReader.start();

out = p.getOutputStream();
out.write((cmd + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
out.write(("exit" + "\n").getBytes(CHARSET_NAME));
out.flush();

p.waitFor();
String result = stdoutReader.getResult();
```

**The class `StreamReader`:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

class StreamReader extends Thread {
    private InputStream is;
    private StringBuffer mBuffer;
    private String mCharset;
    private CountDownLatch mCountDownLatch;

    StreamReader(InputStream is, String charset) {
        this.is = is;
        mCharset = charset;
        mBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        mCountDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    String getResult() {
        try {
            mCountDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mBuffer.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        try {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is, mCharset);
            int c = -1;
            while ((c = isr.read()) != -1) {
                mBuffer.append((char) c);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (isr != null)
                    isr.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCountDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Android 8.1 MiUi 10 Root
I cannot clear any 1 application even with ADB SHELL with SU parameter

Answer (score 4):

On mac you can clear the app data using this command

```
adb shell pm clear com.example.healitia
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To clear Application Data Please Try this way.

```
    public void clearApplicationData() {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null &amp;&amp; dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: i try this,using this can clear our own application cache data, i need to clear another app user data from our application

Comment: @UdayaLakmal you are not supposed to be able to clear another application's cache data, because android is designed to protect applications from potentially malicious actions by other applications.

Answer (score 3):

To clear the cache for all installed apps:

- use `adb shell` to get into device shell ..
- run the following command : `cmd package list packages|cut -d":" -f2|while read package ;do pm clear $package;done`

Comment: ...but this will also clear the applications' data along with the cache, will it not?

Answer (score 1):

To reset/clear application data on Android, you need to check available packages installed on your Android device-

- Go to adb shell by running `adb shell` on terminal
- Check available packages by running `pm list packages`
- If package name is available which you want to reset, then run `pm clear packageName` by replacing packageName with the package name which you want to reset, and same is showing on `pm list packages` result.

If package name isn't showing, and you will try to reset, you will get Failed status.

Answer (score -2):

```
// To delete all the folders and files within folders recursively
File sdDir = new File(sdPath);

if(sdDir.exists())
    deleteRecursive(sdDir);




// Delete any folder on a device if exists
void deleteRecursive(File fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory())
    for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
        deleteRecursive(child);

    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

Comment: This would (if used with appropriate permission) delete the shared files on the External Storage without regard to app association. It **will not** delete the private files of any app, which is what the question was about.