# How do I delete and create a new database with Room?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've made some changes at my android app which works with Room as database, i modified the model of the product which is a table and it returns me this error

Process: com.dam, PID: 13543
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dam/com.dam.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number. Expected identity hash: dba36cbdedaaee568c2a44d54d9a32cf, found: 90f7cc7852b9fac91086fc4d271e92d3

I dont wanna do a migration of the database to another version, i just want to delete the current database and create a new one

Comment: Im using intellij

Answer (score 1):

There could be several ways how to achieve it.

**Delete all app data before launching:**

If this is your device, your application and during development, you can simply download the new version of application and then delete all application data - before starting. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26400275/20755786 via adb or via settings -> applications.

This can be also achieved via API - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#clearApplicationUserData()

**Destructive migration or all data clear in DB**

For this way, you may need to increase the version number first, in order for DB engine to start:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build()
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbackToDestructiveMigration()

If you want just clear all tables (after migration): https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#clearAllTables()